Flutter app doesn't work properly with vscode android emulator
I'm going to learn Flutter. Thus I set the flutter development environment with vscode and android studio. It worked very nice. Flutter doctor have no problem [1], android emulator work properly[2]. But when I try to run flutter sample code where samples tap in the dartpad. It doesn't work in android emulator with eteral roading.[3] However the code work at chrome emulator.[4]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/8McufghT.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/wJSoOKY8.png
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/LhZUGVfd.png
[4]: https://i.sstatic.net/2fp4OZWM.png
I try to install other android virtual device but it doesn't work.[5]
[5]: https://i.sstatic.net/23h8BvM6.png
I try something. Then now if i run code in android studio it's work. No matter emulater or real device.
But running at the vscode it still endless roading with this "Launching lib\main.dart on SM S928N in debug mode..."
Just at vscode, android emulator or real device, run the code occur problem.

It seems like your Android Studio is having issues with its SDK settings.
i) Try running this app on a physical device by enabling USB debugging.
ii) If "point i" runs well on a physical device, try running the code from Android Studio.
iii) If "point i" fails, there could be some issue with the code.
iv) If "point ii" fails, refer to tutorials on how to set up Android Studio SDK Manager settings (SDK platform, SDK Tools) for Flutter. Try that.
v) If "point iv" fails, consider reinstalling Android Studio. Follow "point iv" and then try to run the code on Android Studio and VS Code.

I try to run real device but it doesn't work with eternal "Launching lib\count.dart on SM S928N in debug mode..." like emulator.

Add android emulator extension on VSCode. Or Reinstall VSCode.
